# Voltage drop for a switching device

Tags: voltage

As you know, there are limitation for voltage drop of circuits. Like 5 percent for motors or 3 percent for lighting circuits. 
I saw on a switching power supply that it is compatible with 110 to 240 volt voltage. 
My question is , can we say voltage drop is not problem for this circuits and we can size cable without voltage drop consideration if the cable only supply such a switching power supply. Is there a standard or guide for this?

Comment: The device wold probably work but I'm not sure how wise it would be to drop a significant amount of voltage in the cable. Remember that P=I*U, and you don't want your cable to melt or to set anything on fire.

Comment: The switching supply will have a lower limit. Lets say 110V. If  the input voltage of the SMPS drops below this point then the circuit may not work, its response to change in load may be affected, efficiency would most likely drop.

Comment: It may affect transient response with high line R but normally SMPS have good line filter to store energy for 1 cycle thus reducing conducted and radiated V/m E field.  Power no problem as long as ampacity is not exceeded

Answer (score 1):

Circuits have two limitations, voltage drop, and cable temperature rise, and we have to respect both.

Generally, for home-size installations, with mains voltages, cable temperature rise bites first, and we do a voltage drop calculation/measurement afterwards, just to check.

However, in the case of a long extension lead, or running power to a far-flung outbuilding, we might find that voltage drop can be exceeded without over-temperature on the cable.

In low voltage cases, usually anything over 1m gets limited by voltage drop before temperature rise is an issue.